# mysql check varchar length of json?

Tags: mysql, json

Is there any way we can find varchar length of JSON inputs?

For example, SELECT JSON_LENGTH('[1, 2, {"a": 3}]'); This give output as 3.

But is there any way to find a number of characters in this json? Like we have 19 characters in the JSON input '[1, 2, {"a": 3}]', is there any function that can return this?

We need this to avoid storing very big JSON objects and keep it as safe check before storing any JSON in the database.

Comment: Try [**CHAR_LENGTH**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) function and look also the page for [**string functions**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: working fine. thanks for your help.